# Define variables using eval() within lapply() in R

Tags: r

First I define

```
args <- c("x=5", "y=10")
```

The following has expected behavior in R (creates variables x and y in global environment)

```
for (i in 1:length(args)) {
  eval(parse(text=args[[i]]))
}
```

However the following just returns an unnamed list.

```
lapply(args, function(a) eval(parse(text = a)))
```

Can you use an `apply` function to create the variables instead of a loop?

Comment: In case it's not obvious: You should never do this. Use of `eval(parse())` is a clear sign that your whole approach is flawed and should be redesigned.

Comment: @Roland thanks for the advice. However I am using R CMD BATCH to pass arguments into a R script that I execute from the command line. Is there another way to pass arguments without using `eval(parse())`?

Comment: I bet there is ... You'd need to ask with a more representative example. R-core wouldn't use `eval(parse())` for this (not the least because it is extremely slow). And they have created R CMD BATCH ...

Comment: @Roland I know `Rscript` can accept external variables without having to parse them. The reason I haven't used it is because I cannot figure out how to get it to write console output to a file while the job is still running so I can monitor it.

Comment: So, you have a classic xy problem.

Comment: Well, I didn't realize using eval(parse()) was a problem until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a named `list` and then with `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(args, function(a) eval(parse(text = a))), 
            sub("\\=.*", "", args)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
x
#[1] 5
y
#[1] 10
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite a one-liner!

Comment: i'm not likely touching a 500+k person's one liner.  one small line for 500k+ kind. One huge leap for mere mortals

Comment: @javadba if you have a better option, please do post as a separate answer as I can also learn from that.

Comment: @akrun I did not intend as snark or criticism - more as an observation.  Seeing how to do things in compact and powerful ways is instructive - to the extent we're ready and able to assimilate . I'll take a gander back here after getting more footing in `R`

Comment: @javadba I didn't think as a criticism.  Regarding the reputation remark, from day 1 in SO, I considers others equal and compete with newbies, oldbies etc without any discrimination.  If we think about others reputation, it may not work well.  You need to challenge, compete, etc to improve the skills.  I don't mind getting challenged from anybody as I could learn from otherss

Comment: The rep _does_ matter inasmuch as it indicates many tried and true contributions. But the main driver for my comment is the denseness of your one liner. I'm actually able to decipher it when more carefully examined. Im not used to the `.GlobalEnv` and probably related contexts and that would be something to learn

Comment: it is actually not a one liner :-) written in two lines.  In `base R`, when we wrap the functions, it needs to be split up into inidividual parts to understand what is going on.  Here, a `%>%` with tidyverse makes the flows more easier to understand